# defining path for file in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

In bash I could write a simple script like below; to read the content of a file in the folder as I define the path for the file using environment variable "fileplace"

```
#!/bin/bash

fileplace="/home/vijay/data1/process-folder1/"

cat $file/file1.dat
```

I would like to achieve the same like above in FORTRAN 90, by defining the path using variable. I want to do like this because my folder location path is long and I wanted to avoid using & and + symbol for long lines in FORTRAN 90.

I have tried writing simple FORTRAN 90 code as below for testing.

```
program test_read
implicit none

open (unit=10, status="old",file="/home/vijay/data1/process-folder1/file1.dat")
read(10,*) junk
write(*,*) junk 

stop
end
```

If can I want to avoid using the long path (/home/vijay/data1/process-folder1/) in the FORTRAN code. 
Is there any possibility to achieve this? If yes can anyone help to correct this FORTRAN code? Appreciate any help in advance.

Thank you

Vijay

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fortran isn't a good language to work with strings, but this is still possible.

You need a variable, where you can store the path. If this path is a constant and already known at compile time, you can simply write

```
CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: fileplace = "/home/vijay/data1/process-folder1/"
```

The file can then be opened with

```
OPEN(unit=10, status="old",file=fileplace//"file1.dat")
```

If you want to change the path during execution time, you have to set a appropriate length for `fileplace` and adjust it accordingly, when you want to use it:

```
CHARACTER(100) :: fileplace

WRITE(fileplace,*) "/home/vijay/data1/process-folder1/"
OPEN(unit=10, status="old", file=TRIM(ADJUSTL(fileplace))//"file1.dat")
```

The functions `ADJUSTL()` and `TRIM()` move the content of string to the left to remove any leading whitespace and then cut all trailing whitespace.

Comment: My path is like this (/home/vijay/Simulation-Folder-Feb2013/chapter6-lyo-paper1-Vj/TRAJ-malto12per/). I used in preamble (CHARACTER(*) :: fileplace="/home/vijay/Simulation-Folder-Feb2013/chapter6-lyo-paper1-Vj/TRAJ-malto12per/"). Then in the body of the code i typed (OPEN(unit=31, status="old",file=fileplace//"maltoLyo12per-reimage-set1.traj"). But I get error like this [CHARACTER(*) :: fileplace="/home/vijay/Simulation-Folder-Feb2013/chapter6-lyo-
       1
Error: Entity with assumed character length at (1) must be a dummy argument or a PARAMETER]. Could you give any comment on this? Thanks

Comment: Sry... I forgot the `PARAMETER`.

Comment: The use of a list directed internal write to define a character variable with the value of a character literal constant is unnecessarily convoluted.  A simple assignment statement would be better (that would also allow the reference to ADJUSTL to be removed).

Answer (score 7):

You can use some Fortran like this:

```
fileplace = "/home/vijay/data1/process-folder1/"

open (unit=10, status="old",file=fileplace//"file1.dat")
```

Note:

1. In Fortran string concatenation is expressed by the operator `//`.
2. You'll have to declare the character variable `fileplace`, something like

   `character(len=:), allocatable :: fileplace`

ought to do it.

Fortran 2003 introduced the standard procedure `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` which may also be of interest to you if your compiler implements it.